# Looking for open source javascript implementations of the pubhubsubbub protocol

Tags: javascript, open-source, websub

What are the javascript open source implementations of the PubSubHubbub protocol
publishing side first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to fix your title as it's PubSubHubbub... not PubHubSubbub!
Then, it depends on what side you're asking? *Publisher*, *Subscriber*, *Hub*?

Since all of them need to be able to server files or reply to incoming HTTP requests, you will need to build one with Node.JS, because I don't know of any yet. However, keep in mind that the publisher and subscriber are really easy to implement, so creating a library may actually not make a lot of sense, because you would quickly bump into the limitation of said library.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. That misspelling has shown up by my typing too many times to count now. I'll start simple with a publishing model. I have seen several short scripts (ruby, python, php) that are adequate.

Comment: Feel free to ask for help if you need any. Here or anywhere else :) Also, if you want to use a superfeedr hosted hub, we try to do a good job at helping you go thru the process, but feedback is always appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Julien. There's no harm in publishing through multiple hubs right? So I could push updates to appspot & superfeedr

Comment: Absolutely no harm :) Execpt that the analytics that we provide will become useless, as we won't know how many people susbcribe to the appspot hub!